# Kahoot Clone Deploy on FireBase

Tags: node.js, firebase, bower

I am trying to create a trivia web app and deploy it to firebase. I tried to follow all the steps from https://medium.com/@rotemtam/build-a-kahoot-clone-with-angularjs-and-firebase-b8b30891d968 but at the end, when I deploy my project, the page is blank and the command prompt shows this:

```
=== Serving from 'C:\Windows\System32\amored-cow-trivia'...

i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
!  Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "12"
i  functions: Watching "C:\Windows\System32\amored-cow-trivia\functions" for Cloud Functions...
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4981 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /styles/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular/angular.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/firebase/firebase.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/underscore/underscore.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/app.js HTTP/1.1" 200 548 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/controllers/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 805 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/angularfire/config.js HTTP/1.1" 200 195 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/angularfire/firebase.utils.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2787 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/controllers/chat.js HTTP/1.1" 200 927 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/filters/reverse.js HTTP/1.1" 200 191 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/angularfire/simpleLogin.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1936 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/controllers/login.js HTTP/1.1" 200 726 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/controllers/account.js HTTP/1.1" 200 618 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/directives/ngShowAuth.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1032 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/directives/ngHideAuth.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1042 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/routes.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4857 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/controllers/host.js HTTP/1.1" 200 348 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/services/host.js HTTP/1.1" 200 297 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/controllers/player.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1402 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/services/player.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1882 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /scripts/services/trivia.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1371 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular/angular.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/firebase/firebase.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /bower_components/underscore/underscore.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3529 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:07:00:46 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 4286 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -5):

you COULD just copy n paste the kahoot source code